Spark melt/transpose columns to values
I am trying to transpose the columns of a table to rows
I have a table that looks like this:
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|Date |col_1|col_2|col_...|
+-----+-------------------+
|  1  |  0.0|  0.6|  ...  |
|  2  |  0.6|  0.7|  ...  |
|  3  |  0.5|  0.9|  ...  |
|  ...|  ...|  ...|  ...  |

And the result should look like this:
+-----+--------+-----------+
|Date |Location|   Value   |
+-----+--------+-----------+
|  1  |   col_1|        0.0|
|  1  |   col_2|        0.6|   
|  ...|     ...|        ...|    
|  2  |   col_1|        0.6|
|  2  |   col_2|        0.7| 
|  ...|     ...|        ...|  
|  3  |   col_1|        0.5|
|  3  |   col_2|        0.9|
|  ...|     ...|        ...|

In Pandas I have the following code that does what I need
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Date"], 
               var_name="Location", 
               value_name="Value")

What is the equivalent code in Pyspark?
I have seen a similar question here: Transpose column to row with Spark
However all the answers assume that you can list out all of the columns, In my case I have thousand of columns and the column names are a mix of lat,long coordinates with a mix of other strings.
Is there an equivalent way to achieve what the pandas code does in pyspark?

Here is my solution with explode function:
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, col, explode, struct, lit
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()

data = [{'Date':1, 'col_1':0.0, 'col_2':'a'}, {'Date':2, 'col_1':0.3, 'col_2':'b'}, {'Date':3, 'col_1':0.5, 'col_2':'c'}]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
date_cols = ["Date"]
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c not in date_cols]
explode_cols = explode(array([
      struct(lit(c).alias("key"), col(c).alias("val")) for c in cols
    ])).alias("explode_cols")
t_df = df.select(date_cols + [explode_cols]).select(date_cols + ["explode_cols.key", "explode_cols.val"])
t_df.show(10)

Returns:
+----+-----+---+
|Date|  key|val|
+----+-----+---+
|   1|col_1|0.0|
|   1|col_2|  a|
|   2|col_1|0.3|
|   2|col_2|  b|
|   3|col_1|0.5|
|   3|col_2|  c|
+----+-----+---+

Schema:
root
 |-- Date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |-- val: string (nullable = true)

Tested on pyspark 3.5.1

there is a function melt in Pyspark i don't understand why people are missing it ? did i miss  something ?

Code in gist https://gist.github.com/bresha/3a3f8191f771fe85ec2fbb94c3a36d4e throws error AnalysisException: [UNPIVOT_VALUE_DATA_TYPE_MISMATCH] Unpivot value columns must share a least common type, some types do not: ["DOUBLE" (col_1), "STRING" (col_2)].;  , it can't resolve different column types and poster mentioned that she/he has coordinates and string columns. Code in gist was tested on pyspark 3.5.1

The same function exist in spark 3.4+ pyspark.sq.DataFrale.melt and it hase a close nomenclature :
from pyspark.sql.functions import col 

data = [{'Date':1, 'col_1':0.0, 'col_2':'a'}, {'Date':2, 'col_1':0.3, 'col_2':'b'}, {'Date':3, 'col_1':0.5, 'col_2':'c'}]
    
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

date_cols = ["Date"]
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c not in date_cols]

for column in cols : #cast all column to strings
    df = df.withColumn(column,col(column).cast('string'))

df = df.melt(ids=["Date"], 
               values=("col_1","col_2"),
               variableColumnName="Location", 
               valueColumnName="Value")

